# What does GhostDoc Free do that Visual Studio does not already do?

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, ghostdoc

I am trying to find a way to turn the comments I generate in Visual Studio using `///` into HTML.  It appears that [GhostDoc Pro](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) will do this for me.  And all that GhostDoc Free will do, is generate the comments in Visual Studio.

From what I can tell based on their website is that all GhostDoc Free does is generate the exact same comments that you can do in Visual Studio.  The only difference is pressed `Ctrl Shift D` opposed to `///`.

I doubt such a popular free extension to Visual Studio can only do what Visual Studio already does, and that I am just misunderstanding their website.  So in addition to doing what Visual Studio already does, what does GhostDoc Free do?

I am trying to determine if I need the Pro version to externalize my documentation, but I am also curious if the free version actually does anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with SubMain, the company that makes GhostDoc. I wanted to list the things that the Community (free) edition of GhostDoc does over the built in Visual Studio but there is actually way too many enhancements to cover. So, instead, I thought I would link to the product edition comparison so you could pick the features in the GhostDoc community column that are relevant to your needs - http://submain.com/ghostdoc/editions/?show=expandall

Thanks!

Comment: Good to see you added the ability to generate a basic help file in the free version! Thanks!

Comment: Is it free anymore? I see a 14 day trial...sad that it's gone to a pay model ):

Comment: Yes, the Community edition is free as it has been. The trial is for the commercial version. Download the GhostDoc Community